# Store DICT data in Dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a data in below format:

```
{ 1: ( a1, 10) , (a2,20) , (a3,30)}
```

want to store in the dataframe

```
a1 10
a2 20
a3 30
```

Comment: You code is not a proper Python dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

well actually your code is in little improper format 
but check if this can help

```
 x={ 1: ( 'a1', 10) , ('a2',20) , ('a3',30)}
```

you have made a mistake of not putting a1,a2,a3 in 'quotes' this will return you tuple values

```
pd.DataFrame(x)
x
#this prints
0 (a1,10)
1 (a2,20)
2 (a3,30)
```

but if you want output like you requested you have to do like this

```
you should use list for multiple values since its more easy 

df=pd.DataFrame({1:['a1','a2','a3'],'val':[10,20,30]})
df
#this prints
  1 val
0 a1 10
1 a2 20
2 a3 30
```

hope this helps